# How to start from root activity not from sub activity when app restart?

Tags: android, android-activity

After task killer kills app when I am in sub activity and if I restart app, it starts from sub activity and crashes. 
How to start from root activity not from sub activity when app restarts?

Comment: Please try to read about manifest file,And Check you have used <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> within your root activity tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to add

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

to the `activity` definition in the manifest for your "root" activity (the one with ACTION=MAIN and CATEGORY=DEFAULT).

However, this will always start your app from scratch if the user leaves it and then returns to it (even if Android hasn't killed your apps' process).

A more complicated way to do this is to use a `public static boolean` variable which you set to `true` in `onCreate()` of your "root" activity. If this variable is `true`, that means that your "root" activity has been started. You then need to test this flag in `onCreate()` of all your other activities, and if the variable is `false` that means that Android killed your process and recreated it and launched another activity (not the "root" activity). In this case, you should redirect back to your "root" activity like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyRootActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
return;
```

Comment: I didn't try because I found cause of crash. But I think the second method works.

Answer (score -2):

This might work:
In your sub Activity's onStop and onDestroy, put following code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent = null;
```

Comment: This answer is not useful. When the application process is killed, it is killed. It doesn't exist anymore. `onStop()` and `onDestroy()` will not be called. When the user starts the app again, Android remembers which Activity was on top and restarts that activity. It is normal and your answer won't change that.

Comment: @DavidWasser : David android restarts that activity but it restarts the activity with same intent. Thats why I think this can work. Yes you might be right onDestroy might not get called, so the location for writing these two lines can be different, this is what I think . If you can share some light in more details of life cycle when android kills an activity.

Comment: When you call `getIntent()` like this, it sets a local variable called `intent` to a reference to the `Intent`. Then, you set this local variable to null. What do you think this is going to accomplish?